Solving by elimination an analytical geometry question about circles



I came across this question on Quora which has been solved by one of the Quora user.
The thing is that he has used the method of elimination to get to the final solution rather than solving it the traditional way.
Step 1: He eliminated option A & C of Q18, as it is not possible for any element in List I to match more than 1 element in List II. Answer has to be among B or D.
Step 2: From Q18, (I)(P) & (III)(R) are correct. So, we can cancel the options A & B from Q17. Answer has to be among C or D.
Step3: In Q18,we need to ascertain whether (IV) matches (S) or (U).

He eliminated 21/5 by proclaiming that alpha can't be a factor of 7 and the 3's & 4's in the equations make 10/3 the more probable answer. (through Pythagoras, as 10 is a multiple of 5)
Step4: In Q17, we need to ascertain whether (II) matches (Q) or (T).

He eliminated 2√6 proclaiming that for a real number(2,here) to get out, large numbers like 64 should replace the 16 in the given equation of circle.
Can someone explain how he deduced that alpha can't be a multiple of 7? Please explain the square root approach as well.
I understood the first two steps of eliminating the options. But I'm not able to understand the next two approaches. I can solve it the traditional way but that is way too lengthy.
Quora question link

Questions posted here should be as self-contained as possible.

There is a lot to read on that link. Exactly which part are you asking about? It would really help if you could transcribe just that part into your question here. Otherwise, many people will just move on to questions that are more clearly written.

That Quora contributor, Sunny Dhondkar, doesn't seem to have any activity there within the last 11 months (and the question itself is 5 years old), but you still might consider posting a comment asking for clarification. Or perhaps write directly to the email address provided on their profile page.

@Red Five, I have edited the question to make it more understandable.
